# _msearch vs _search performance

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

`_msearch` is used for multiple searches in one go. This alone is a performance improvement since it reduces the network overhead. 
Right now I'm using `_msearch` like the `_search` endpoint, for single queries. I wanted to have this mechanism in place for future batch processing. Until I take advantage of the batch processing will this introduce an overhead? Does `_msearch` behave exactly the same as `_search` for single queries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a very small overhead in the sense that even if you have one query, the `_msearch` endpoint will still need to iterate over it and create a single search query.

However, I would consider this overhead as clearly negligible.

Comment: Yes I agree. I was afraid of something like elasticsearch doing something clever with the queries in order to boost the overall performance. Something like smart caching of some sort, in order to take advantage of the 1st query's results for the 2nd one, etc (if they are one the same index of course).

Comment: Any query **might** benefit from what was cached when processing the other queries. The normal search infrastructure is leveraged for the multi-search endpoint, too, but multi-search is merely a way to shrink-wrap multiple queries in one go, much the same way as bulk queries can wrap multiple index queries

Comment: Thanks for the followup. Upvoted and marked. Have fun

Answer (score 0):

_msearch is multi search it takes a little over head than the _search because 
The multi search API allows to execute several search requests within the same API.